# How do I add onclick functionality to a custom button on admin side?

Tags: magento2, custom-button

I am able to add a button to Product Listing page.
But how do I add onclick to it?

This is how I am adding the button:

```
$subject->addButton('amazon_sync_button',[
            'label' => __('Sync with Amazon'),
            'id' => 'amazon-sync-button',
            'on_click' => 'setLocation(\'' . $this->sync() . '\')'
        ]);
```

I have created a function sync(), but this gets executed even before button click.

I saw some answer using getURL(), but I am not sure how to achieve it.
Can anyone guide me on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php


use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface;

class Sync implements ButtonProviderInterface
{
 /**
  * @var \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Container
  */
 public $container;
 /**
  * Url Builder
  *
  * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
  */
 public $urlBuilder;
 /**
  * Registry
  *
  * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
  */
 public $registry;
/**
  * Sync constructor.
  * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context
  * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
  * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Container $container
  */

 public function __construct(
     \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context,
     \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
     \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Container $container
 ) {
     $this->container = $container;
     $this->urlBuilder = $context->getUrlBuilder();
     $this->registry = $registry;
 }
 /**
  * @return array|bool
  */
 public function getButtonData()
 {
     $id = $this->container->getRequest()->getParam('id');
     if (!empty($id)) {
         $data = [
             'class' => 'action-secondary scalable delete',
             'label' => __('Sync with Amazon'),
             'on_click' => "syncConfirm('Are you sure you want to do this account?','".$this->getSyncUrl($id)."')",
             'sort_order' => 20,
             'data_attribute' => [
                 'url' => $this->getSyncUrl($id)
             ],
         ];
         return $data;
     }
     return false;
 }

 /**
  * @return string
  */
 public function getSyncUrl($id)
 {
     return $this->urlBuilder->getUrl('*/account/sync', ['id' => $id]);
 }
}
```